# How can I dispaly more than one (different) model objects to one tempate django

Tags: python, django

I want to dispaly both models object in my index.html template, but its not working..

models.py
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VjBi.jpg)

views.py[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZVDc.jpg)

Comment: Post your code in text format

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode - well, I didn't downvote actually, it's your first post here ;-) But please read the link above (as well as [ask] and [mcve]) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Also note that "is not working" is a totally useless description of a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite the `get_context_data()` method in the list view to add your other model to the context. This website is really helpful for understanding class based views. https://ccbv.co.uk/